# How to make a select statement to return "NULLs" if the value is a repetition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Lets take we have:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, Salary, TaxPercentage
FROM Employees
```

returns:

```
 Name |Surname     |Salary  |TaxPercentage
-------------------------------------- 
Moosa | Jacobs     | $14000 | 13.5
Temba | Martins    | $15000 | 13.5
Jack  | Hendricks  | $14000 | 13.5
```

I want it to return:

```
 Name |Surname   | Salary  |TaxPercentage
-------------------------------------------  
Moosa | Jacobs   |  $14000 | NULL
Temba | Martins  |  $15000 | NULL
Jack  | Hendricks|  $14000 | 13.5
```

Since TaxPercentage's value is repeated, I want it appear only once at the end.

Comment: How to find the last record i mean the end

Comment: Could show the rest of the columns of the `Employees` table - there must be some identifier/way to order the data.

Comment: **BatchID** is an additional column which returns common values i.e 135, Employees are Grouped/divided into **BatchIDs**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In sql server 2012 and above you can use the [`Lead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125(v=sql.110).aspx) window function to get the value of the next row. Assuming you have some way to sort the data (like an identity column), you can use this to your advantage:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Surname, 
       Salary, 
       CASE WHEN TaxPercentage = LEAD(TaxPercentage) OVER (ORDER BY Id) THEN 
         NULL 
       ELSE 
          TaxPercentage 
       END As TaxPercentage 
FROM Employees
ORDER BY Id
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa954/1) (thanks to [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen))

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't use `LEAD()` then this should work:

```
with T as (
    SELECT
        Name, Surname, Salary, TaxPercentage,
        row_number() over (order by TaxPercentage /* ??? */) as rn
    FROM Employees
)
select
    Name, Surname, Salary,
    nullif(
        TaxPercentage,
        (select t2.rn from T as t2 where t2.rn = t.rn + 1)
    ) as TaxPercentage
from T as t
```

Comment: you have a typo in the inner select (`selecdt`), and I don't understand why you are using coalesce - you should return null if the `TaxPresentage` is equal to the next row - I think it should be something like this: `nullif(TaxPresentage, (select TaxPresentage from t as t2 where t2.rn = t1.rn+1)) as TaxPresentage`

Comment: I was thinking that I needed to handle the case where the subquery returns null on the final row. But you're right that I should have just reversed the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You should have some way to order the data in order. In my example, I am using simple `IDENTITY` column, in your it could be primary key or date:

```
DECLARE @DataSource  TABLE
(
     [Name] VARCHAR(12)
    ,[Surname] VARCHAR(12)
    ,[Salary] VARCHAR(12)
    ,[TaxPercentage] DECIMAL(9,1)
    --
    ,[RowID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Name], [Surname], [Salary], [TaxPercentage])
VALUES ('Moosa', 'Jacobs', '$14000', '13.5')
      ,('Temba', 'Martins', '$15000', '13.5')
      ,('Jack', ' Hendricks', '$14000', '13.5')
      ,('Temba', 'Martins', '$15000', '1.5')
      ,('Jack', ' Hendricks', '$14000', '1.5')
      ,('Temba', 'Martins', '$15000', '23')
      ,('Jack', ' Hendricks', '$14000', '7')
      ,('Temba', 'Martins', '$15000', '7')
      ,('Jack', ' Hendricks', '$14000', '7')

SELECT [Name]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Salary]
      ,[TaxPercentage]
      ,NULLIF([TaxPercentage], LEAD([TaxPercentage], 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [RowID])) AS [NewTaxPercentage]
FROM @DataSource;
```

Answer (score 1):

I need a column to sort rows like Id with identity column

```
;with cte as (
SELECT
    Id, Name, Surname, Salary, TaxPercentage,
    LEAD(TaxPercentage, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS NextValue
FROM Employees
)
select
    Id, Name, Surname, Salary,-- TaxPercentage,
    TaxPercentage = CASE WHEN TaxPercentage = NextValue THEN NULL ELSE TaxPercentage END
from cte
```

Please check [SQL Lag()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lag-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-previous-values.aspx) and [Lead() functions](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lead-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-next-value.aspx) for more detail on these new analytical functions

Answer (score 0):

Work with SQL Server >= 2008 if needed
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec020/1/0

```
Select o.Name, o.Surname, o.Salary
, TaxPercentage = case when o.id = 1 then o.TaxPercentage else null end
From (
    Select Name, Surname, Salary, TaxPercentage
    , id = row_number() over(partition by TaxPercentage order by Name, surname, Salary) -- update order...
    From Employees as e
) as o
order by o.TaxPercentage, o.id desc
```